# how to add custom action in sugarcrm?

Tags: sugarcrm

So i have a custom module **MLB** what i want is add a custom action in detailsview.php for a button to send **Messages**, i already have the action but i have no idea how i put it !!

Answer (score 0):

You can override **\custom\modules\{modules_name}\views\view.details.php** display function like this:

```
<?php
if(!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

require_once('include/MVC/View/views/view.detail.php');

class modules_name extends ViewDetail {

    function modules_nameViewDetail(){
        parent::ViewDetail();
    }

    function display(){
        // include your custom function code here
        parent::display();              
    }   
}

?>
```